# How to save an image that is inside a div with paperclip?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I am trying to save an image that is inside a DIV with the gem paperclip but I don't know how get image from de div for can save it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload the image to your controller using a form. Only then it will be saved by paperclip.